# c++ - Build systems in Sublime Text, Windows 8

Tags: c++, build, sublimetext2

I'm just beginning to learn programming (on C++), and by beginning I mean total beginning ("hello world" beginning...). Not wanting to use multiple IDE's, I would like to be able to code and build–simple–programs with my text editor, Sublime Text 2. Could someone indicate me, with a step-by-step tutorial, how to implement C++ compiling and executing capabilities in Sublime Text.

I've searched Sublime Text build systems on the site, but the answers are very specific and can't help a rookie like me (but they'll probably help me later).

Thanks

Comment: If you're just starting, maybe a C++ only IDE would be a better choice? You can always switch back when you get familiar enough with C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 will allow you to build .cpp files within the application, but you must have the GNU c++ compiler installed on your machine and defined on your path in order for it to work.

The following link provides a version of g++ for you to use and has detailed instructions for doing this

http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html

once youve installed g++ you'll be able to build your .cpp file and run it from with in sublime text 2.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: btw... I have sublime text as well, and until I read your post I never thought about using it for c++.  Anyway, I followed the guide in the link above and was indeed able to install g++, run it from the command line, then subsequently build and run a simple prog in sublime text 2! Let me know If you run into any SNAFUs

Comment: Thanks @Ben Glasser. I installed g++ exactly as directed on the site, and added the path as told, and restarted. Now it gives me this error upon building: g++: : No such file or directory
g++: No input files
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]

Comment: close and restart sublime text, if that doesn't work make sure you correctly installed it on your path correctly by opening a command prompt and typing g++ then hitting enter.  you should see a message saying "no input files" or something similar

Comment: Yes, it says g++: No input files

Comment: @LeonardoLopez hrmmm, how are you trying to compile your prog?

Comment: In ST2: Tools/Build. The error before mentioned comes up on the bottom terminal

Comment: I'm at a loss cause thats exactly how I did it and it worked fine.  This sounds like a dumb question but did you save your file before building?  something like hello.cpp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18831/discussion-between-ben-glasser-and-leonardo-lopez)

Comment: I am so embarrassed. I saved it and it prints Hello World! on the bottom console. What I assumed was that when I closed Sublime Text, it saved the untitled file automatically. Guess I was wrong. One last question. When I run the program, the following warning comes up: bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
Hello World!
[Finished in 0.2s]  Any ideas on how to fix that warning? Where eaxctly do I need to create that temp folder?

Comment: awesome! I'm glad it worked out. As far as that error goes then you also need to define a tmp directory on your path.
you can do that by creating a directory anywhere on your disk, like C:\temp
then in environment variable reate a new variable called TMP and set its value to C:\temp
then add %TMP% to the end of your path

Comment: Solved!! The bash warning was simply creating a tmp folder in the root C:\tmp.  Thank you very much! @BenGlasser